# Highlight The Menu

Tags: php, codeigniter, menu, highlight

I have a doubt in highlighting the menu using php code.

I am developing a website using codeIgniter framework.Now I want to highlight the menu after clicking the particular menu.

Please help me to highlight the menu using php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `view` pass variable which will have

```
   $data['selectedItem'] = '';

   $this->load->view('blogview',$data);
```

In `blogview`

```
  <li class="<?php echo $selectedItem == 'menuItem1' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">menuItem1</li>
  <li class="<?php echo $selectedItem == 'menuItem2' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">menuItem2</li>
```